# CGPDFDocumentCreateWithURL will download the file in to documents directory or not

Tags: iphone, pdf, cgpdfdocument

I am accessing the PDF files available in my PHP server using my iPhone with the help of passing file url to CGPDFDocumentCreateWithURL. My question whenever i access the files it will downloaded to my iphone documents directory or not?

Because if my application in active for some time i am getting the error CFURLCreateDataAndPropertiesFromResource with error code -14. After getting this error my application is not crashed but it is not functioning properly.

I am not able to  understand the internal process? Please help me in this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're misunderstanding what `CGPDFDocumentCreateWithURL` does. It does not download a PDF document to the filesystem. It creates a PDF in memory based off the URL provided. It doesn't save anything to the filesystem.

I would *strongly* recommend you use a networking class (NSURLConnection, ASI, etc) to download the PDF *first* and then open it. This will enable you to provide better feedback, and support more advanced download features such as resuming partial downloads, providing progress, and better thread management.

Comment: Thanks :) But how to download and save the pdf file for first use and use the saved document for later purpose

Answer (score 0):

To save the PDF

```
NSString *urlString = @"http://www.web.com/url/for/document.pdf";

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];

NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];

NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);

NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

NSString *pdfPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"myLocalFileName.pdf"];

[data writeToFile:pdfPath atomically:YES];
```

then load that saved file into a web view:

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);

NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

NSString *pdfPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"myLocalFileName.pdf"];

NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath: pdfPath];

NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

[[self mainWebView] loadRequest:request];
```

Comment: This isn't a great way of doing it, or at the least you should be running it off the main thread. `dataWithContentsOfURL` is a synchronous method, which is ill advised for networking.